# Any idea why have this CORS error policy?

Tags: php, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc

I have a project developed with Angular (frontend) localhost:4200, this project in a future will be in production, I commented this just in case if someone help me with the solution and keep this in mind, also have a webservice developed with asp.net core 6, in my .net project have enable the jwt authentication, everything works fine when I consume api´s(controllers) but I have an error when I try to consume an API developed in PHP, this api is already in production in a plesk server, the error in console is the next one : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'php api location' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
This is my configuration program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var appSettingsSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
var llave = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secreto);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(d =>
{
    d.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    d.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(d =>
    {
        d.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        d.SaveToken = true;
        d.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(llave),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

It is important also to mention that I use local storage to save token when an user login in my application and have an interceptor and look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

    constructor( private apiauthService : ApiauthService ){}

    intercept( request : HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

        const usuario = this.apiauthService.usuarioData;
        //console.log(usuario);

        if (usuario) {
            //console.log('entra');
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${usuario.token}`
                }
            });
        }

        //console.log(request);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

The php file have this configurations:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
```

And that is all, if someone have any idea to solve this problem.

Comment: *"Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."* - In your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` PHP configuration, I see no `Authorization` header allowed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${usuario.token}`
    }
});
```

Requests are being sent with an additional header named `Authorization`.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers:` would need to have `Authorization` added specifically for it to be allowed. With this config, `Authorization` is simply an implicitly denied header.

Try adding it to the allowed headers block and see if it helps!

For similar examples have a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#examples